# After Spring upgrade from 5.2.x to 5.3.x - No mapping for GET

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

After upgrade from Spring 5.2.x to 5.3.x, the error message `DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound Message=No mapping for GET /sampler/`

Sample code -- https://github.com/hth/sampler working fine with 5.2.12 lib

Comment: where is your `/sampler` endpoint in your code? I do not see it... I only see home https://github.com/hth/sampler/blob/master/view/src/main/java/com/sampler/view/controller/HomeController.java

Comment: `/sampler` is Application context set by IntelliJ and it takes care of it. I tried without its and it gives the same error - `noHandlerFound Message=No mapping for GET /`

Comment: I agree with ch271828n, can't find a /sampler endpoint in your code. Can you add more info abour the behaviour before the update to 5.3.x? Were you able to make a succeful GET request to /sampler?

Comment: @ch271828n, @santiago-wagner Please read this https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war#1-deploy-directory-or-war-file-located-on-server. Its just a name. If you want a `/` as ROOT then war deployment has to be named as ROOT.war instead of sampler.war. Please run the code to see it.

Comment: @java_dude what about /open/home?

Comment: @ch271828n Same message - No mapping for GET `/open/home.htm`. Note: This issue is just with 5.3.x and not 5.2.x spring (same code base)

Comment: @java_dude remove that `.htm` what happens

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to a [change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/25260) where additional beans are registered with the `DispatcherServlet`.

Specifically, the [DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.html) bean is now loaded in 5.3.x, which may be transforming the URI to a view name.

You may be able to disable this behavior by setting the `stripLeadingSlash`, `stripExtension`, and `stripTrailingSlash` properties to `false`.

Try adding the following bean definition to your `root-context.xml` file.

```
<bean id="viewNameTranslator" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator">
    <property name="stripLeadingSlash" value="false" />
    <property name="stripExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="stripTrailingSlash" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. Added above code but got the same result `No mapping for GET /`